# Default Android Browser Error Page Source

Tags: browser, html

I'm wanna ask, where locate source file of default Android Web error page (that shows when for example URL address is wrong)?

> [image: like this page]
>   <sup>Example page (click image to enlarge)</sup>

I just found `NOTICE.HTML.gz` in system files.

Comment: Quite curious about it as well - thanks for bringing it up. +1

Comment: I guess it'll be inside the app (apk) as an asset.. Whenever there's these errors, the HTML asset file might be loaded from the app by the app..

Comment: But page style like that showing and in another applications that shows internet content as is.

Comment: Other apps could utilize the built-in WebView too, and thus return the same error page as the browser who also happen to use the same WebView.

Comment: Hm... In my LineageOS 14.1 I found system WebView application, but I'm not sure that there is any html samples or builder in xml files...